# Different compression sizes using Python and C++

Tags: python, c++, zlib

I am using zlib for compressing some data, and I am running into a weird issue: data compressed with python is smaller than the one using C++. I have 130MB of simulation data I want to save compressed(too many files for all the necessary data).

Using C++, I have something of the sort:

```
//calculate inputData (double * 256 * 256 * 256)

unsigned int length = inputLength;
unsigned int outLength = length + length/1000 + 12 + 1;
printf("Length: %d %d\n", length, outLength);

Byte *outData = new Byte[outLength];

z_stream strm;
strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
strm.next_in = (Byte *) inputData;
strm.avail_in = length;
deflateInit(&strm, -1);

do {
    strm.next_out = outData;
    strm.avail_out = outLength;
    deflate(&strm, Z_FINISH);
    unsigned int have = outLength - strm.avail_out;
    fwrite(outData, 1, have, output);
} while(strm.avail_out == 0);

deflateEnd(&strm);
delete[] outData;
```

The result using C++ is around 120MB, which is hardly what I expect, as the original is close to 130MB.

In python:

```
from array import array
import zlib
// read data from uncompressed file
arrD = array.array('d', data)
file.write(zlib.compress(arrD))
```

The result using Python is around 50MB using the same input data, less than the half. The C++ code is mostly based on the one using in python's [implementation](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/zlibmodule.c?revision=81098&view=markup), which makes this issue even weirder.

For C++, I am using Visual Studio 2010 Profession with Zlib 1.2.8 compiled by myself. 
For Python, I am using the official python 3.4.2.

Comment: 1. Do both compressions use exactly deflate? 2. Are they using the same block sizes etc (since compression needs to deal with "fitting in reasonable amount of memory", the algorithm typically has a max size of data that it "looks at as one lump" - but it's often configurable to allow for tuning performance vs. memory use)

Comment: @MatsPetersson I am not sure about the zlib parameters as I haven't used it that much. But looking at the python source code, it doesn't do anything special with the default parameters. As for the z_stream parameters, I have used the same as the ones used in python.

Comment: How do you know that it's the same input data?

Comment: @MarkAdler because it is my own data and I've made sure to use the same data. That said, I did figure out why python had a better compression rate: some precision was being lost when saving the data for python(double to float conversion). I did get some better compression when shaving off precision on the C++ side.

Comment: Double to float?!  That's half the size!  "same input data" means the same bit-for-bit.  It wasn't the same input data, not by a long shot, since it was half the size.

Comment: Indeed you are right. I did only notice this long after I asked the question though.

Comment: You may want to answer your own question and mark it for future answer seekers.